# JSP как изменить атрибут required у поля INPUT по условию?

Tags: javascript, jsp

У меня есть поле input c опцией required=true и есть кнопка submit.
Мне нужно, чтоб при нажатии submit у поля input опция required становился false.

```
<table style="width: 100%">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input class="form-control col-5" name="agent" id="agent" value="${agent}" placeholder="<spring:message code="report.missedCalls.agent"/>" required="true">
  </td>
  <td align="right">
   <button id="refresh" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg small btn-primary" onclick=checkform()>
    <spring:message code="report.refresh"/>
   </button>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function checkform()
    {
        $("#agent").required=false;
    }
</script>
```

но что-то у меня не работает отключение required.

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию атрибут required выключен, поэтому нужно просто его удалить:

```
<input id="agent" required>
<button  type="submit" onclick=checkform()>Button</button>

<script>
  function checkform() {
     $("#agent").removeAttr("required");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: и в голову не пришло... я только не пойму, почему $("#agent").required=false; не работает...

Comment: Не встречал такой формы записи с false/true, для этого атрибута не требуется такое уточнение. Если атрибут required есть, значит поле обязательно к заполнению, если отсутствует, то поле может быть пустым. Тут логика такая: есть атрибут - true, нет - false.